# Understanding <?php print $node->content['body']['#value']; ?> in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

sorry, this is a really noob question...

When I want to print part of the $content array within node.tpl.php (for example), I'll use something like `<?php print $node->content['body']['#value']; ?>`

I just want to understand what the `->` is all about. Presumably this indicates that `$node` is something other than a normal array? ( Otherwise it'd be `$node['content']['body']['#value']` )

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$node is an object and content is one of its properties, containing an array.

If the contents of 'content' was also an object, it would be

$node->content->body etc.

Comment: Not "items", the correct term is "properties" (as opposed to e.g. "dimensions", which are accessed with `[]`).

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but the devel module is awesome.  You could install devel and use

```
<?php dpm($node); ?>
```

and you will see a lot of information that will help you with your theme-ing. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider installing Theme Developer module. With it you can click on elements of your page, and you will get a debug list of all the Drupal or Views related variables which can be accessed by  your code.

So you can explore $content, and all it's fields...

Comment: Theme Developer used to be part of the "devel" module, by the way, but is now its own project called "devel_themer"